# c# mock return base method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am writing a unit test case with NUnit framework to test our code.

The code has referenced to 3rd party libraries like below:

```
class MyClass: BaseClass
{
    public void override FunctionA()
    {
      var a = BaseFunctionB();
    }
}
```

we don't have sourcecode for `BaseClass`, but the `BaseFunctionB` is non-virtual.

I was trying to

```
Setup(x=> x.BaseFunctionB()).Reteruns("my values");
```

but it doesn't allow.

I just want to test the `FunctionA` in `MyClass`, I don't care whether it's correct in `BasefunctionB`.

How to test in this case?

----------------------------2018-01-03 updated---------------------------------
I made some update for the `BaseClass`:

```
public abstract class BaseClass1//we dont have source code for this class
{
    public int GetValue()
    {
        //do something here
        return 1;//
    }

    public abstract int GenerateOutPut();
}


class abstract class BaseClass2: BaseClass1
{
    public new virtual int GetValue()
    {
        return base.GetValue();
    }
}

class MyClass1: BaseClass2
{
    public override int GenerateOutPut()
    {
        var a = GetValue();
        a += 1;
        return a;
    }
}

class MyClass2: BaseClass2
{
    public override int GenerateOutPut()
    {
        var a = GetValue();
        a -= 1;
        return a;
    }
}

// there are many MyClass
class MyClassN: BaseClass2
{
    public override int GenerateOutPut()
    {
        var a = GetValue();
        //different logic here.
        return a;
    }
}
```

i made a class for testing `MyClass1` like below:

```
class TestClass1: MyClass1
{
    public override int GetValue()
    {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

test case as below:

```
public void TestFunction()
{
    var test = new TestClass1();
    var result = test.GetValue();

    assert.AreEqual(101, result);
}
```

Now I have to create many `TestClas` which looks not good. but in terms of running out code coverage, i have to make it( i try to use mock object to execute, there is no code covered in report, i guess because it create proxy and run it on proxy, so i create the same thing myself to test the original source code)

Do i have a better solution?

Comment: Is the base class `TheirClass` abstract? if not then I would suggest not mocking what you do not own. encapsulate the 3rd party dependency behind an abstraction you control and then explicitly depend on it so as to allow you the flexibility to mock/stub/fake any desired behavior for testing. It also allows for better maintainability of your code.

Comment: Could you provide context closer to how the actual class works. This example is still too broad, which will make it more difficult to provide a viable solution.

Comment: You can configure moq to call the base members of the mock. In this case for example you can mock `MyClass1` telling the mock to call base members and then setup the `GetValue` to behave as desired for your test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the second base class and the new member to encapsulate the 3rd party dependency was a good idea. It allows you to override the member in derived classes. In general try to avoid mocking what you do not own. Instead encapsulate 3rd party dependencies behind an abstraction you control so as to allow you the flexibility to mock/stub/fake any desired behavior for testing.

Using `MyClass1` from your example

```
public class MyClass1 : BaseClass2 {
    public override int GenerateOutPut() {
        var a = GetValue();
        a += 1;
        return a;
    }
}
```

The following test can be done to verify the expected behavior from the subject under test. Note Moq allows for base members to be called by setting `CallBase = true` on the mocked object.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyClass1_Test {
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyClass1_Should_Generate_Output() {
        //Arrange
        var expected = 0;
        var mock = new Mock<MyClass1>() {
            CallBase = true //<-- let mock call base members
        };
        mock.Setup(_ => _.GetValue()).Returns(expected); // <-- mocked behavior

        var sut = mock.Object; //<-- subject under test.

        //Act
        var actual = sut.GenerateOutPut();

        //Assert
        actual.Should().Be(expected + 1);
    }
}
```

Which is almost like what you did manually but now via the mock proxy.

Comment: why `sut.GenerateOutPut();`? that doesn't looks correct at all ... the call should not be on a mock instance of the class.

Comment: @Rahul it was meant for demonstrative purposes. There are edge cases where the class under test needs to be mocked because of some members needing to be overridden.

Comment: Which looks wrong ... call should be on `new MyClass1().GenerateOutPut()` and *not* on a mocked instance.

Comment: @Rahul The OP needed to override `MyClass1().GetValue` which is what `GenerateOutPut` depended on. So the concrete class was mocked and configured to override the `GetValue` and also to call the actual `GenerateOutPut` when invoked (`CallBase = true`).